# Full Qualified name

Tags: java, eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree, qualified-name

I need to extract all the fully qualified names present in a Java source code. Could anyone point me in the right direction? 
i have to transforme all qualified names to an import instructions. More details : do what ctl+shift+M do. And it must be authomatique in total abstraction to the user and the fonction wille be asked after each modification of the source code. The java source code files are generated bay an other gerator (meta language) and i can not modify the generator.
i can not use shift+ctrl+M because it must be authomatic

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: You can select multiple classes in Eclipse, right-click and do `Source > Organize Imports`.

Comment: it must be authomatique in total abstraction to the user and the fonction wille be asked after each modification of the source code. The java source code files are generated bay an other gerator (meta language) and i can not modify the generator

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use [JavaCC](http://javacc.java.net/).
There is already a Java [grammar](http://java.net/projects/javacc/downloads/directory/contrib/grammars) that you can use to detect all the FQN you need in the source.

Comment: this is what i am doing: cu=compilation unit                                                               AST ast = cu.getAST();                     cu.recordModifications();
List<ImportDeclaration> imports = cu.imports();      ImportDeclaration _import = ast.newImportDeclaration();  _import.setName(QualifiedName);//here i must found all qualified names declared in the source code
imports.add(_import);

Comment: If OP just wants identifiers that are involved in fully qualified paths, then a parser will do.   If he wants, for each encountered identifier, a fully qualified path, then a parser falls far short; he needs a full symbol table.  See http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/LifeAfterParsing.html for why parsers aren't generally the answer.

Comment: @ Andrew Thompson this is what i am doing `AST ast = cu.getAST();
  cu.recordModifications();
  List<ImportDeclaration> imports = cu.imports();
  ImportDeclaration _import = ast.newImportDeclaration();
  _import.setOnDemand(true);
  List<TypeDeclaration> types = cu.types();
  for(TypeDeclaration type : types) {
      if(type.getNodeType() == ASTNode.QUALIFIED_NAME) {
       int index = types.indexOf(type);
          // Class def found
             _import.setName(types.get(index).getName());
          }
      }` do you think that is correct to do this?